# Unable to enter BIOS

Tags: grub2, startup

On start-up with my Dell M5030 device, I have not been able to access Setup when the computer starts.  I have pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> at and shortly after starting the computer, however Grub 2.0 starts.

Please advise as to a work around to suppress Grub 2.0 long enough to access the BIOS.

Comment: **@the_Seppi**: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)
**user263281**: according to the [Dell M5030 Manual](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-m5030/manuals) the key is [F2].  Just turn on the machine and immediately press it and keep it pressed until the BIOS shows up!

Answer (score 2):

If you are directly thrown to the GRUB menu, it's too late for pressing those keys. By this time, GRUB has already "taken over control" of your computer.

So you have to press the appropriate key(s) before. I've looked it up on Dell's website: The key required for entering the BIOS Setup menu is <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Unless your system is quite old, in which case some of those combos may work for you:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⏎ Return</kbd>
- <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (laptop only)
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (laptop only)

In case there is no time to press the appropriate key(s) "[At the first text on the screen or when the Dell logo appears](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN114872/)", try pressing it/them **before** pressing the power button and **keep the key(s) pressed** until the Setup menu or an according message appears.

Comment: Good man!  Upvoted!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you Fabby.  I figured it out last night with enough trial and error, but another factor I had not considered was that I was trying to use reboot, and a cold start is what finally worked.   Again, Thanks.  GB